How does changing the elevation angle allow starlink to improve line of sight communications
According to this article: https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2024/10/spacex-claims-starlink-can-offer-gigabit-speeds-if-fcc-approves-new-plan/

SpaceX seeks to lower its minimum elevation angle from 25 degrees to 20 degrees for satellites operating between 400 and 500 km altitude," SpaceX told the FCC. "Reducing the minimum elevation angle in this way will enhance customer connectivity by allowing satellites to connect to more earth stations directly and to maintain connections with earth stations for a longer period of time while flying overhead

Why would this improve the communications ?

I think image should clarify what the angle means.

The elevation angle is counted from "horizontal" and so the antenna of the satellite can "see" a cone underneath, with tip angle 90°-elevation.
Obviously the lower the elevation value the wider the cone base - the antenna can "see" ground stations in wider area. In the picture, the 25° elevation cone catches the station nearer to the satellite, but only the 20° elevation cone has the other ground station in line of sight.
Of course the station will be farther and so the connection to it will be weaker which may be counter-intuitive if you want to improve the connection - but the weaker connection is still better than if no ground station is in range and the satellite needs to forward the comms through other Starlink satellites that do have a ground station "in sight".

Oh so it’s not a different orbit but rather the angle range of the antenna ?

@Antzi Note this also means the ground stations broadcast "flatter", meaning the signal lobe may affect other objects on the ground, which is likely a legal hurdle.
